# app_offline.htm file being used to take webservice offline - possible to read contents of file?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using an app_offline.htm file as described here :  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx to take an old asmx web service offline.

All works fine, and the client end gets a HTTP 503 exception like :

```
Exception : System.Net.WebException
The request failed with HTTP status 503: Service Unavailable.
Source : System.Web.Services
Stack trace :
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
```

My question : is it possible for the client application to read the contents of the app_offline.htm file which would have been returned ? The basic HTML in that file has helpful text like : "The application is currently undergoing maintenance". I can see the contents of this file being returned in the response using Fiddler.

It would be useful to be able to parse this html response to provide more info to the user. (i.e. so it is possible to distinguish between a 503 error due to system maintenance, and other 503s due to system being overloaded etc).

**EDIT** : BluesRockAddict's response sounded good, but the stream seems to be unavailable at this time. e.g. :

```
            // wex is the caught System.Net.WebException 
            System.Net.WebResponse resp = wex.Response;


            byte[] buff =  new byte[512];
            Stream st = resp.GetResponseStream();

            int count = st.Read(buff, 0, 512);
```

The last line above which attempts to read the stream gives :

```
Exception : System.ObjectDisposedException
Cannot access a closed Stream.
Source : mscorlib
Stack trace :
   at System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

credit goes to BluesRockAddict, adding to his answer, this is how you can read the content of html page.

```
catch (WebException ex)
{
    if (((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable)
    {
        using (Stream stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var message = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's useful. Although ideally, I'd like to use my web service proxy class, which this won't work with (because the stream seems to be disposed by this time).

Comment: @MoeSisko i have already tested with wcf service and client proxy. it is working fine. that's why I have posted this as answer.

Comment: sorry, I meant I'm using old style asmx web service (non wcf). I'll mark your anwser as accepted since it comes closest to meeting my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [WebException.Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx) to retrieve the message:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        string content = wc.DownloadString(url);
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        if (((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable)
        {
            message = ex.Response
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: This may work, but I'm not in a position to change the web service calling code, just to get this functionality. But +1 for trying.